# How to deserialize a nested Array from xml to c# object?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, soap, xmlserializer

I'm trying deserialize the following `soap xml` response from my web service to a `C#` object:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns2:ExportPositionsQueryResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ns" xmlns:ns3="http://nscpm/datatypes/schema/v2011_06_01" xmlns="http://nscpmexportvalue/schema/v2011_06_01">
      <ns2:Positions>
        <FieldTypes>
          <FieldType ExtId="PF_NAME" Type="string"></FieldType>
          <FieldType ExtId="POSITION_QUANTITY" Type="double"></FieldType>
          <FieldType ExtId="INST_NAME" Type="string"></FieldType>
          <FieldType ExtId="INST_TYPE" Type="string"></FieldType>
          <FieldType ExtId="POSITION_TYPE" Type="string"></FieldType>
          <FieldType ExtId="POSITION_CLASS" Type="string"></FieldType>
        </FieldTypes>
        <Position>
          <Field ExtId="INST_NAME" Value="name"></Field>
          <Field ExtId="INST_TYPE" Value="asd"></Field>
          <Field ExtId="PF_NAME" Value="ads"></Field>
          <Field ExtId="POSITION_CLASS" Value="asd"></Field>
          <Field ExtId="POSITION_TYPE" Value="asd"></Field>
          <Field ExtId="POSITION_QUANTITY" Value="asd"></Field>
        </Position>
        <Position>
          <Field ExtId="INST_NAME" Value="asd"></Field>
          <Field ExtId="INST_TYPE" Value="asd"></Field>
          <Field ExtId="PF_NAME" Value="asd"></Field>
          <Field ExtId="POSITION_CLASS" Value="ads"></Field>
          <Field ExtId="POSITION_TYPE" Value="NORMAL"></Field>
          <Field ExtId="POSITION_QUANTITY" Value="asd"></Field>
        </Position>
        <Position>
</ns2:Positions>
    </ns2:ExportPositionsQueryResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

After deserialization, `xmlSerializer` creates an object only with element `FieldTypes` and the last element of `Position`. I think `XmlSerializer` has a problem with the nested `Array(PositionField[][] Position)` and can't deserialize all `Position` array elements. Here is part of my `C#` object class, which I'm using for deserialization:

```
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://ns")]
    public partial class ExportPositionsQueryResponsePositions
    {
        private FieldTypesFieldType[] fieldTypesField;

        private PositionField[][] positionField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Namespace = "http://ns")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("FieldType", IsNullable = false)]
        public FieldTypesFieldType[] FieldTypes
        {
            get
            {
                return this.fieldTypesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.fieldTypesField = value;
            }
        }
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray(ElementName ="Position",Namespace = "http://ns")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("Field", typeof(PositionField[]), IsNullable = false)]
        public PositionField[][] Position
        {
            get
            {
                return this.positionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.positionField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

For creating this class, I've used the "Paste special" function of Visual Studio. But also with the `svcutil` tool I get same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. I should edit automatically generated proxy client class. I've replaced all `nested arrays [][]` with `List<T>` and serialization works again. here's example:

**wrong generated part of code:**

```
private PositionField[][] positionField;

public PositionField[][] Position
    {
        get
        {
            return this.positionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.positionField = value;
        }
    }
```

**edited part of code:**

```
 private List<PositionField> positionField;

 public List<PositionField> Position
    {
        get
        {
            return this.positionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.positionField = value;
        }
    }
```